# Dart package dependency to subdirectory of git repo

Tags: git, dart, dart-pub

I have a couple of small dart demo projects together in one git repository. Thus each project is in a subfolder of the repository and the yaml files of each of these projects is in the corresponding folder, not under the root of the repo. Is there a way to specify a git dependency to such a subfolder within a git repo? I know that I can clone the repository manually and use a file path in the dependency specification. But what I'm looking for is a way to have a direct git url for that package in a subdir. Is this possible?

Comment: have you tried to add the directory name to the URL?
`git: url: git://github.com/munificent/kittens.git/somedir`
The documentation only mentions `ref: some-branch` (The ref can be anything that Git allows to identify a commit) see https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies.html#git-packages

Comment: This doesn't work, because pub triggers a git clone first, but the url with appended directory does not refer to a valid git repository and so the clone fails.

Comment: I guess you should make a feature request dartbug.com/new

Comment: I create a feature request. See https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19797

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Several years on, support for this has been added:

https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/pull/1650

You can now split the `git` dependency into a `url` and `path`:

```
dependencies:
  protobuf:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/dart-lang/protobuf.git
      path: protobuf
```

Further reading: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I got from the dev team:

"This isn't something we're planning to support. Repos should have one-to-one correspondences with packages, and the packages should be located at the top level of the repos."

This makes it difficult to use dependencies to packages in a git repository as Eclipse always uses the project root as subfolder in the repository.

Comment: This is now possible - see my answer :-)