# How to add a nested package from GitHub as a dependency tp pubspec?

Tags: flutter

How do I use a nested package on GitHub?

I have forked a repository that has subfolder `packages` with the main package and other packages it depends on.

When I try to use this nested package like this

```
audioplayers:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/JonasJW/audioplayers/tree/main/packages/audioplayers.git
    ref: main
```

I get the error

```
Git error. Command: `git clone --mirror https://github.com/JonasJW/audioplayers/tree/main/packages.git /Users/jonas/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/git/cache/packages-c53372e52e6b77435233d1879066ce0db95c1888`
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/jonas/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/git/cache/packages-c53372e52e6b77435233d1879066ce0db95c1888'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/JonasJW/audioplayers/tree/main/packages.git/' not found
exit code: 128
```

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: Use `path` to the subfolder. I think similar question has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53760890/13617136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `path` Parameter to define path of your package root folder

Update dependency in your pubspec.yaml like this:

```
dependencies:
   audioplayers:
     git:
       url: https://github.com/JonasJW/audioplayers.git
       ref: main
       path: packages/audioplayers
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: How about in cli command? Since path is not within git parameter

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to explain, can you please elaborate?

Comment: like how can i achieve that while using the cli? example 

`flutter pub add package_a --git-url=https://${{ secrets.token }}@github.com/company/package.git --git-ref=develop --git-path=packages/abc`

but --git-path and --git-url doesnt co-exist in  flutter pub add

Comment: But what's the reason behind the CLI approach when you can directly copy paste the dependency in `pubspec.yaml`?